# Razor view engine intellisense not working VS 2010

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Inside VS 2010 I do not have any intellisense working. I have reinstalled everything and still nothing is coming up for intellisense???

Comment: Do you have resharper installed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have resharper installed then you'll need this [update](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/02/resharper-513-is-released/) which should fix it.

Comment: Have you tried changing the IntelliSense from Resharper to VS or vice-versa?

Comment: On VS tool bar go to Resharper > Options which will bring up a dialog box. Then in the dialog box its Environment  > IntelliSense > General

Answer (score 2):

@Cameron - The issue is caused by Resharper not automatically "triggering" intellisense in Razor documents.  You can manually invoke the intellisense using Control-Space.  So @DateTime. will not give you any options, but if you do @DateTime. and then hit control-space it will bring up the intellisense for the DateTime object.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue with VS2010, although ReSharper had never been installed in VS2010.  However, ReSharper was installed in VS2008, and the VS2010 installation had copied the Intellisense settings in the registry from the VS2008 installation.

To fix the problem, without buying a VS2010-compatible version of ReSharper to switch the Intellisense back, I had to edit the following entries in the registry.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Text Editor\CSharp]  
"Auto List Members"=dword:00000001  
"Auto List Params"=dword:00000001
```

Before my edit, both of these read 00000000

This re-enabled VS2010 to provide the intellisense.

Comment: I had these configurations in place, but still no result. I never used ReSharper.